# converting auth_views.login from django 1 to 2

Tags: python, django

I'm reading the book "Learning Python" and I've come across an issue with the chapters project. The project uses an older version django so I've had to modify some items, but this one really has me stuck. Basically the auth_views.login needs to become auth_views.LoginView. Same for logout. I can't figure out how to "convert" the code over to the new method.

I've taken a look at the documentation and the docs don't show an apples to apples example of the projects workflow (using regex urls). This throws a position argument error (takes 1, 2 were given)

tried replacing :

```
url(r'^login/$',
    auth_views.login,
    kwargs={'template_name': 'admin/login.html'},
    name='login'),
```

with :

```
url(r'^login/$',
    auth_views.LoginView(template_name='admin/login.html'),
    name='login'),
```

to no avail.

Below is a full snippet.

```
# regex/urls.py
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from entries.views import HomeView, EntryListView, EntryFormView


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^entries/$', EntryListView.as_view(), name='entries'),
    url(r'^entries/insert$',
        EntryFormView.as_view(),
        name='insert'),

# here lies the troublemaker
    url(r'^login/$',
        auth_views.login,
        kwargs={'template_name': 'admin/login.html'},
        name='login'),

# as well as here
    url(r'^logout/$',
        auth_views.logout,
        kwargs={'next_page': reverse_lazy('home')},
        name='logout'),

url(r'^$', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
]
```

Comment: You need to use `as_view`, like you have for the other views.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I got it working finally. with a few tweaks.